# How to fix that error on android studio (gradle build)?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Recently when I started my  android studio I got an annoying error in event log:

```
PicoPluginExtensionInitializationException: org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.GradleManager has unsatisfied dependency: class org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.GradleInstallationManager among unsatisfiable dependencies: [[class org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.GradleInstallationManager]] where DefaultPicoContainer (root) was the leaf container being asked for dependencies.
```

and when i try to sync the gradle another message appear :

```
IllegalArgumentException: Can't retrieve external system settings for id 'Gradle'. Reason: no such external system is registered
```

how can i fix it ?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please provide detailed data such as: android studio version, gradle version, build tools version, etc.

Comment: Please specify your project code@Zaky Aris